# Continuous map of a compact set

Tags: general-topology

Claim: If $f:X \to Y$ is continuous, where $X$ is compact, and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $f$ is a closed map.

Proof: Take $A \subset X$ to be closed in $X$. Now as $X$ is compact and by choice of $A$ we have that $A$ is compact. Thus $f(A)$ is compact, since the image of a compact space under a continuous space is compact. So, $f(A) \subset Y$ and since every comapct subset of a Hausdorff space is closed $\Rightarrow f(A)$ is closed.

Question: Does everything seem to be correct here? I am only questioning this because it followed to quickly from previous lemmas and proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct.

There's a very unfortunate typo: At the end you want to conclude that $f(A)$ is closed, so *"$\Rightarrow$ $A$ is closed"* should be *"$\Rightarrow$ $f(A)$ is closed."*

I would also make it more explicit that we are using the fact that closed subsets of compact spaces are compact, so I'd write something like *"Since closed subsets of compact sets are compact, it follows that $A$ is compact."* instead of *"By the choice of $A$"*.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. Yeahm I slipped on the typo.